# Adding multiplied corresponding elements from two different lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists with same length:

```
list00={10, 6, 8, 6, 9, 7, 9, 5, 7, 10};
list0={0, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 5};
```

and another list:

```
mainlist={1, 2, 4, 10};
```

I wish to sum multiplied corresponding elements of `list00` and `list0` according to mainlist:

```
sum=10*0+6*5+6*4+10*5;
```

my code is:

```
sum = 0; Do[  sum += list0[[i]]*list00[[i]]
, {i, mainlist}]
```

**Question:**

If I have two distinguishable and different `mainlist`s for `list00` and `list0` seperately, how can we do this process (adding multiplied corresponded elements):

```
list00={10, 6, 8, 6, 9, 7, 9, 5, 7, 10};
list0={0, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 5};

mainlist00={1, 2, 4, 10};
mainlist0={1, 3, 5, 8};

*desired result:* 10*0+6*2+6*3+10*3;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list00 = {10, 6, 8, 6, 9, 7, 9, 5, 7, 10};
list0 = {0, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 5};

mainlist00 = {1, 2, 4, 10};
mainlist0 = {1, 3, 5, 8};

Times @@@ Transpose[{list00[[mainlist00]], list0[[mainlist0]]}] // Total
```

> 60

or using `Dot`

```
list00[[mainlist00]].list0[[mainlist0]]
```

> 60

With one "mainlist" it would be

```
mainlist = {1, 2, 4, 10};

Times @@@ Transpose[{list00, list0}][[mainlist]] // Total
```

> 104

Or

```
list00[[mainlist]].list0[[mainlist]]
```

> 104

Comment: +1 for the `Dot` method

Answer (score 1):

```
☺ = #[[#2]].#3[[#4]] & @@ # &;

☺ @ {list00, mainlist, list0, mainlist}
```

> 104

```
☺ @ {list00, mainlist00, list0, mainlist0}
```

> 60

Comment: ... this is the `Dot` product of the selected `Part`s of the  of the two lists.